# Why can't a class member's name be the same as one of its nested classes?

Tags: c#, properties, conflict, nested-class

Or why is the following impossible:

```
class Material
{
    class Keys
    {
        ...
    }

    Material.Keys Keys { get; set; } // Illegal
}
```

I don't see any possible ambiguity. When accessed by instance, return the property. When access statically, return the class. Or am I missing something?

I'm not asking for a "fix" (I know I could just name it differently, like MaterialKeys or the like), but more of a technical reason behind this limit.

Comment: This is the scenario that I would to see work.  It makes total sense that I want to declare an inner class and to declare a member of that type in the outer class.  The outer class contains exactly one instance of a thing that it defines.  That thing is not designed to work in any other context so it makes sense that both the class and member are in the same namespace (meaning the outer class is the namespace ... not the c# namespace keyword).  To have both the class and the member in the same (outer) class, I have to name one of the differently.  But which one do I want to have a weird name?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

But imagine you had this:

```
class Material
{
    class Keys
    {
        ...
    }

    static Material.Keys Keys = new Keys();
}
```

Now both are at "static" scope.  Now, can the compiler disambiguate in all cases?  If not, then this can't be allowed.

I suppose it's possible that the disambiguation would work for static fields/properties/methods, and not for instance members.  Or the other way around.  If that were the case, would you want the language specification to allow an instance member to have the same name as an internal class, but disallow it for statics?  That would just be confusing.

But then, having a member match the name of an internal class is pretty confusing anyway.

Comment: Very reasonable... reason. Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's confusing for a member to match its type name or the name of an internal class. They are used differently: one is a class and one is a property name. There should be no confusion there. That doesn't negate your first point, which is spot on. There is no way to differentiate between the `Material.Keys` class and `Material.Keys` static member. That's pretty much a deal breaker for this mechanism. What I would say is that if one is presented with this situation, they should consider if they are being as descriptive as possible in their naming. `KeyCollection` instead of `Keys`

Comment: "Would you want the language specification to allow an instance member to have the same name as an internal class, but disallow it for statics?" Yes I would.

Answer (score 16):

"Anything that's not ambiguous should be legal" is absolutely NOT a design principle of the C# language. The C# language is designed to be a "pit of quality" language; that is, the rules of the language should throw you into a pit full of clearly correct code, and you have to work to climb out of the pit to turn it into incorrect code. The idea that "whatever is not ambiguous should be legal" works in most cases directly against the concept of a "pit of quality" language.

Furthermore, your idea that I need to provide you a justification for not doing a feature is backwards. We don't *ever* need to provide justification for *not* doing a feature. Rather, **proposed features must be justified by demonstrating that their benefits outweigh their enormous costs**. Features are very expensive and we have a limited budget; we must only do the very best features to yield their benefits to our customers.

Your proposed feature enables the easy production of code that is brittle and confusing; it helps make C# into a "pit of despair" language instead of a "pit of quality" language. Features which add brittleness and confusion to the language must add an enormous benefit to compensate for those costs. **What is in your opinion the enormous benefit that this feature adds to the language that justifies its costs?**

If the answer is "there is no such benefit" then now you know why the language doesn't have that feature: because it makes the language worse, net.

If there is a benefit, I'm happy to consider its merits for hypothetical future versions of the language.

Comment: I didn't imply there was any great benefit. I simply wondered about the semantics of the language. Obviously StackOverflow is not just a "pit of understanding".

Comment: I do think there is benefit to the feature.  A class that can define a class and a member of that type makes for good encapsulation.  I do understand the ambiguity issue and I wonder how that could be resolved.  Maybe we live with more ambiguous code (although that is not the C# way).  Or we add something to the language to allow this feature.  Maybe a special syntax for an inner class that allows for this.  I don't know what it would be, but something that eliminates the ambiguous issue.

Comment: One of the convenient uses is when you have a class that exposes an enum that pertains only within it's context. For example, let's assume we have an `enum ReportType`. Now I may want a property called ReportType of type "enum ReportType". I'd rather not clutter that enum outside this class as I'd like to refer to it as `Foo.ReportType.MyFancyReport`. These kind of situations are quite common when creating model classes.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: The benefit would be that you could actually map SQL entitites to CLR-entities without needing a mapper,. e.g. "table message with field message varchar(X)", map to "class message{ public string message;}" when the table and column name consist of valid c# identifiers. Right now, this isn't possible, and you need to rename either the table or the field, or use mappers that slow down data-fetching - all of which is bad - and if you have an existing db with many existing queries/updates/interfaces, renaming a field/table isn't really possible. Talking about "pit of quality" ...

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Not having certain features can also be a pit of despair.

Answer (score 5):

You said,

> When accessed by instance, return the property. When access statically, return the class.

But what if you say just `Keys` somewhere inside `Material`? Is this a static or instance access? Does this refer to the property `Keys` or the nested type `Keys`? It is actually ambiguous.

For example,

```
class Material
{
    class Keys
    {
        public static int Length;
    }

    string Keys { get; set; }

    public void Process()
    {
        // Does this refer to string.Length (via property Keys)
        // or Material.Keys.Length? It actually refers to both.
        Console.WriteLine(Keys.Length);
    }
}
```

As pointed out in the comments, this is not the whole story; but almost. It is valid to have a property named `Color` of the type `Color` and there is no clash:

```
public Color Color { get; set; }

Color.FromName(...)   // refers to static method on the type ‘Color’
Color.ToString()      // refers to instance method on the property’s value
```

But this is easy to resolve simply because things in the current scope win over things in more outer scopes:

```
public class MyType { public string FromName(string name) { return null; } }
public MyType Color;

Color.FromName(...)   // unambiguously refers to MyType::FromName(string)
                      // via the property Color
```

Not so easy in your example — the nested class `Keys` and the property `Keys` are in the same scope (have the same declaring type). How do you decide which to give priority? And even if you did decide to give one of them priority, this would be only marginally useful because you could still only have two things of the same name, and one would have to be static and the other instance.

Comment: The "this" keyword could fix this. I am getting an ambiguity exception when I do "this.Keys.Length".

Comment: This isn't the full story; purely by this reasoning, `public Color Color { get; set; }` should also be illegal.

Comment: @Ani - when you use `Color` in that context it will use the member instance first.  Using the fully qualified name of `System.Drawing.Color` will give you access to the `Color` class.  This isn't the same problem since your class still only has one member called `Color`, it just happens to use another class called `Color`.  Distinguishing between them is trivial.

Comment: @Lazlo Sure, `this.Keys` works for the property, but there is no way to explicitly reference the `class Keys`.  That is a problem - you should always be able to explicitly reference a class.

Comment: @Michael Shimmins: "Distinguishing between them is trivial." Not really. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/06/color-color.aspx

Comment: @Kirk Broadhurst: Yes, there is. "Material.Keys" references it.

Comment: @Ani: This example really shouldn't compile and complain about an ambiguity, but it's not on topic at all.

Comment: @Lazlo - `Material.Keys` also references your member variable of type `Material.Keys` - thus the problem.

Comment: @Michael Shimmins: I need to see an example of ambiguity for this last statement. I really don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Ani - that blog post confirms exactly what I said.  Qualify it with a type name to resolve the difference.  Still pretty trivial.

Answer (score 4):

My answer approaches the question from a slightly different perspective, compared to the other questions. Of the following two statements in a C# language specification:

```
The same identifier may not be used in different definitions within one scope
```

and

```
The same identifier may not be used in different definitions within one scope, unless it is probably impossible for any ambiguity to arise when the identifier is used
```

, the first is much simpler.

Simplicity is a key goal in language design, because simpler languages are easier for compiler and interpreter authors to implement, easier for tools to generate and manipulate, easier for beginners to learn, and easier for programmers to understand. When considering any language feature, the complexity that that feature adds to the language should be considered as a negative, and must therefore be balanced by an at least equal measure of usefulness. As you stated yourself, allowing this would add no real functionality (as it is so easy to work around), so there was no compelling reason to further complicate the C# spec by including it.

Comment: I agree that it's _easy_ to fix the problem -- name the member different than the type. But, I'm struggling with that. One will get the meaningful name and the other will get a weird name -- some derivative that is different only because it needs to be different ... not because naming it differently makes the code more readable.  For example, if I name the member Field, what do I name the type?  FieldType, FieldClass, _Field?  Nothing I put on the word "Field" does anything but make the reader ask: why is the type name different than the class name?

Answer (score 3):

Because the nested class `Keys` is a member of `Material` as is the property `Keys`.  You've got two members called `Keys`.

In the same way you can't have two properties called the same thing:

```
public class Bar
{
    private bool Foo { get; set; }
    private string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

When you access `Foo` which one are you trying to access?

```
public class Material : Keys
{

    private Keys K { get; set; }
}

public class Keys
{

}
```

Works fine, but is probably not what you're after.

Comment: I agree that you can't have to instance members defined by the same name, but why can't you have a static and an instance member of the same name? You can't possibly confuse them. "Material.Keys" is not the same as "new Material().Keys" at all.

Comment: What about when you access `Keys` from inside `Members`?  Which one is it, static or member? `public Material() { Keys. // which one? }`

Comment: I don't know for you, but my compiler never allowed me to assign a nested class from an instance. Therefore `new Material() { Keys }` would definitely be the instanced one.

Comment: Put backticks around it.  Its not about assignment its about resolution.

Comment: @Lazlo, it is **legal** (though poor code style) to access a static member through an instance.   Therefore, they would indeed collide.  The *key* lesson is that nothing that is classified as a **member** can share the same name and enclosing type.